# ImportError when using google.cloud library in app engine dev

Tags: google-app-engine, python-import, importerror

I have done the following, installed google cloud in a local lib folder with pip. Added an appengine_config.py file:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add("lib")
```

But still get:

```
ImportError: No module named google.cloud.bigquery
```

It seems there is some kind of conflict in the `google` namespace, since other dependendices in the lib folder seems to be possible to import.

If I just override with:

```
google.cloud.__path__ = ['/Users/okku/dev/MyServer/lib/google/cloud']
```

Then it works, but some other dependcy failes to be imported in this case `google.api_core`.

I have been on this for half day now. I cant find whats wrong. Any clues?

Comment: Looks right.  Is the `lib` directory at the same level as your `app.yaml`?  Try restarting your instance.

Comment: Yes same level and already restarted all that can be restarted.

Comment: In your `__init__.py` try adding this at the top:  `import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'lib')`

Comment: Try importing the bigquery module directly in your remote shell or interactive console, to see if you can get a traceback for the underlying error?  `ImportError` implies that bq is having trouble with one of its dependencies.

Comment: I have hardcoded all the paths for now, in the dev env. I think there is some conflict with the site packages and the lib folder. By just hardcoding and making sure the lib folder is the first in the path, its working. Maybe @GAEfan sys path insert solution does that but more general way. Will try it as soon as possible.